# Filter Core Data results by property BETWEEN

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I currently have Core Data successfully returning all of the results for a specific entity titled Event:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" 
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchResults = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Now in time of calendar plotting i need to fetch those events which start date on or before this month and end date is also on or after current month.

I believe the answer relates to NSPredicate but I am not familiar enough with it yet to get it to bend to my will.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: You want the login for fetch data between current month?

Comment: @PetahChristian this is the predicate  NSPredicate *predicateClass = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(field_start_date >= %@) AND (field_end_date <= %@)", startDate, endDate];

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition to predicate:

```
NSDate * firstDateOfMonth = [self returnDateForMonth:month year:year day:2];
NSDate * lastDateOfMonth = [self returnDateForMonth:month+1 year:year day:1];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startDate => firstDateOfMonth) and (endDate <= lastDateOfMonth)”];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event"                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;

NSArray *fetchResults = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: your query is partly correct coz it will effect only those start-end date which is belongs to the month but suppose one event started on november 2014 and will end on november 2018 , that case it will not work ... right?

Comment: Yes that time it will not work. You need to modify that condition as per your requirements.